# Magento 2 Translate Checkout

Tags: magento2, js-translation

I've been encountering an issue where I am unable to translate fields in Magento 2 checkout.

Steps I have take:

1. Created `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/i18n/en_US.csv`
2. Added strings to update:

   "Review & Payments", "Review & Pay", 
   "Apply Discount Code", "Apply Promotional Code"
3. Ran the following:

   ```
   bin/magento setup:upgrade
   bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento setup:content-static:deploy en_US
   ```

When refreshing the frontend, the translation in the checkout does not update. However, using the same steps works for all other front-end aspects of the site.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Comment: I've read over that and it doesn't work on the checkout pages. All other pages work well with my approach. I've been reading that it might be related to the js-translation and knockout not updating but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Check if your translation are in js-translation.js in your pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US

Comment: The file is there but is returning only [] which I believe means it is not properly collecting the KnockOut translations. I found a post suggesting moving the templates from the checkout into the custom theme and just updating the translation there, and that would work in the short run but we are also planning a french version down the road and at that point would be back where we started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much head banging and trying I finally figured out what the problem was. Localizing inside a theme such as `app/design/frontend/Company/theme/i18n/en_US.csv` does appear to get incorporated into the knock-out translations in the checkout. Why? I'm not sure, but I did come up with a solution that worked by creating an entire language pack.

Step 1, create a CSV of all translatable phrases used in the store. Run the following in ssh:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o en_US.csv -m
```

Step 2, create a language pack such as `app/i18n/CompanyName/en_US/` instructions on creating dictionaries and language packs are available in the Magento 2 developer documentation at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html

Step 3, Update the phrases in the language pack to match the translation and localization needs

Step 4, refresh caches and deploy via ssh:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

A full write up including each step for creating a language pack can be found at http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/translation-localization-of-a-magento-2-store/

Comment: bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o en_NZ.csv -m

In Phrase.php line 90:

  Missed phrase


Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Before you delete this empty file

Normally this file is generated by language you have to launch a

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR en_US
```

tell me if that work

Comment: I am using php bin/magento setup:content-static:deploy en_US (we don't have a french translation yet)

Comment: Ok it's just an example this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no it does not. It creates the js-translation file but it only contains []