# Magento 2 - translations on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, localisation, i18n

I've got a big issue with Magento 2.3.1, and translations on checkout, for store made in two langs - EN and PL. (PL set as default store)

I've got a custom template, with elements that override Luma, and PL lang pack from Mageplaza (https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-polish-language-pack) installed in copy&paste method, because of need to override some translations (placed correctly in `app/i18n/Polish/pl_PL/` with adjusting Vendor to that directory). Besides one payment gateway, no more plugins that can influence those views.

On all of the places, translations work correctly, but on the checkout page, it seems like most translations were switching back to EN ones - step titles, minicart, some form fields like auth

What I've checked to make this work:

- known issue with older versions of Magento 2 - `Json\PreProcessor` and `Area::PART_DESIGN`
- redeploying everything (like `setup:static-content:deploy pl_PL`) with cleaning caches, cleaning manually cache and pub dirs
- changing `translate="'Shipping methods'"` to `data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping methods'"`
- defining theme translations
- defining module translations
- checking localStorage for `mage-translation-storage` - which surprised me, cause it contains correct dictionaries
- toggling inline translations, and repeating cache clear, etc.
- finding out, what we have got in generated `js-translations.json` - that seems to be correct.

The issue was found on my local env, same as on dev and pre-prod envs (deployed with deployer.org, with default M2 recipe)

Have anyone some other ideas, what I can try to get this working? :)

Comment: What if you create full lang pack and translate it there php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o pl_PL.csv -m ???

Comment: Kamil, Please refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203816/39238

Comment: Same thing. Created package with `i18n:collect-phrases`, changed all occurences of some example strings from checkout. Than pushed that generated .csv into created language pack. Checked that also as pushed into theme translations. Still english phrases in checkout :/